# Docking station activity light constantly on

Tags: hard-disk, cpu-usage, temperature, dock-station

I just bought a new 10tb internal hard disk, which I connect to my pc, by running a usb cable to an external docking station.  For some reason, the docking station's activity light is constantly blinking, for this new hard disk.

I would like to know why this is happening, and whether I should simply ignore the situation, or try to remedy it.  Further details below:

---

My O.S. is linux mint 20  : cinnamon.  I normally back up my data to either a 6tb hard disk or a 3 tb hard disk, both of which are several years old.  Both hard disks are internal 3.5 inch hard disks that I connect to my pc by running a USB cable to an Aluratek docking station.  The docking station is also several years old.  Anytime that I use the docking station, I use a large $20 fan directly on the hard disk to prevent its overheating.

The connection to both hard disks is fine.  When I use either hard disk, the docking station's activity light (apparently) is only blinking when performing IO on the hard disk.  When the hard disk is lying idle, the docking station's activity light does not blink.

Recently, I bought a new western digital 3.5 inch internal 10tb hard disk, and partitioned and formatted it with the following commands:

```
lsblk
    this was used to determine that the hard disk has been assigned to device sde.

sudo parted /dev/sde
     mklabel gpt
     mkpart primary ext4 1MiB 100%
     quit

lsblk 
    (again) to verify that partition is now assigned to sde1.

mke2fs -t ext4 -L tv_movies_ttb_01 /dev/sde1 

use nemo file mgr to open (i.e.) mount hard disk.

sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sde1 
    done to reclaim space.

sudo chmod -R 777 /media/steve/tv_movies_ttb_01/
```

The above procedure is the exact same procedure that I used to initialize the 6tb and 3tb hard disks.  Further, I have done moderate testing on the 10tb hard disk, by using rsync to copy files to it.  The 10tb hard disk seems to be working perfectly.

With the 10tb hard disk lying idle, and the docking station activity light continuing to blink, I used the `sensors` command to verify that the pc (apparently) is not overheating.

I ran the top command and took a couple of sample screenshots, which are shown below.  What should I do about this situation; ignore it or seek a remedy?

---

[image]

[image]